# Retrieve values from SQL database - EF

Tags: sql, asp.net-mvc, entity-framework, razor

I'm trying to figure out how to pull values from a SQL database and display this in a razor view.

I have the following class using Entity Framework (I believe)

```
public class EventLog
{
    [Key]
    public int Id { get; set; }
    public int EventId { get; set; }
    public int MaxDelegates { get; set; }
    public string Code { get; set; }
    public DateTime End { get; set; }
    public string Title { get; set; }  
}
```

And I want to map title to `DBTitle` in the following model:

```
public class CourseDetailVM : CourseDetailSummaryVM
{
    public EventLog DBTitle { get; set; }
}
```

I then want to see this in the following view:

```
@using TSW.Web.Helpers
@model TSW.Web.ViewModels.CourseDetailVM

@{
    Layout = "~/Views/_Master.cshtml";
}

@Model.DBTitle.Title;
```

I have the following controller already in place (sorry for the length I plan to reduce this down):

```
public class CourseDetailController : BaseRenderController<CourseDetailPageDT>
{
    private readonly ISitePageFactory _pageFactory = null;
    private readonly IEventService _eventService = null;

    public CourseDetailController(IEventService eventService, ISitePageFactory pageFactory)
    {
        _pageFactory = pageFactory;
        _eventService = eventService;
    }

    public async Task<ActionResult> CourseDetail()
    {
        var homepage = _pageFactory.GetCurrentHomepage();

        var model = Mapper.Map<CourseDetailVM>(CurrentContent);

        model.Email = homepage.ContactEmail;
        model.PhoneNumber = homepage.HeaderPhoneNumber;

        model.InnerPageHeader.ShowHeading = true;
        model.InnerPageHeader.Title = model.PageTitle;

        if (model.Categories.Count == 1)
        {
            var categoryTagId = model.Categories.First().Id;

            var contentTypeAlias = DocumentTypeHelper.GetDocumentTypeAlias<CourseListingPageDT>();
            var courseCategoryPage = Umbraco.TypedContentAtXPath($"//{contentTypeAlias}")
                .FirstOrDefault(x => x.GetPropertyValue<int>(Constants.DocumentTypes.CourseListingPage.Category) == categoryTagId);

            if (courseCategoryPage != null)
            {
                model.InnerPageHeader.BackLink = Mapper.Map<LinkItem>(courseCategoryPage.Id);
            }
        }

        try
        {
            model.Events = await _eventService.GetEventsForCourse(CurrentContent.AdministrateId);
        }
        catch (Exception ex)
        {
            model.Events = new StaticPagedList<Event>(Enumerable.Empty<Event>(), 1, 1, 0);
            Elmah.ErrorSignal.FromCurrentContext().Raise(ex);
        }

        if (CurrentContent.Graphic != 0)
        {
            model.InnerPageHeader.Graphic = Mapper.Map<CtaItem>(CurrentContent.Graphic);
        }

        return View(model);
    }
}
```

I've tried every suggestion I can google to add the mapping in the controlling but can't get my head around this simple function of pulling the value from a SQL database into the razor view.

Could anyone help me out?

Comment: Sorry, you need to create a [mcve]. Right now, we have no idea which bit isn't working or even what isn't working. Do you have an error message? Which line is the error on?

Comment: @DavidG - Not so much an error. I'm really looking for how do I retrieve the SQL database values from EventLog and pair it with a variable in the CourseDetailVM so that I can then use that in the Razor View (aka title in database is "First Aid" I want to have this available to print into the razor view). I've not used EF before so I'm quite lost as to the correct syntax

Comment: Like I said, create an [mcve] then we can help. I'm sure that 90% of the code above is not needed to help you solve your problem.

Comment: Yeah, tough to sift through that. For starters, don't include EventLog (which appears to be an entity) in your view model. Looks like you already have AutoMapper so use that to get the desired entity properties into the VM. You mention EF, so somewhere in your code or service you should have a DbContext. Use that to get data from SQL and then map it into your ViewModel. i.e. `var eventLog = context.EventLogs.Find(myId);` Then map those to your VM.

Comment: Thanks for your comments. I'll take this on board and have another go. Biggest problem i've faced is much of the code i've inherited so I'm trying to build upon existing code that I'm not 100% certain how its working which is not exactly clear in these situations!